# Rails 4 - validation doesn't work for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have a model called `RateIndex`:

```
class RateIndex < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :car

  validates :name,        :presence => true
  validates :car_name,    :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true
  ...
end
```

The controller is `rate_indices_controller.rb`

```
class RateIndicesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @rate_index = RateIndex.new
  end
  ...
```

And the form:

```
<%= form_for(@rate_index) do |f| %>
  <% if @rate_index.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h3><%= "#{pluralize(@rate_index.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this game from being saved:" %></h3>
      <ul>
        <% @rate_index.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  ...
```

But when I send the empty form, there are no validation errors displayed... I've tried to also change the validation rules, but even then they are ignored.

I am kind of blind from it, looking into it quite a while, but still nothing.

I'd be grateful for every help here.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

```
def create
  @rate_index = RateIndex.new(rate_index_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @rate_index.save
        format.html { redirect_to '/rate_indices/new', notice: 'Rate was successfully added.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @rate_index }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @rate_index.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Please, add the `ReateIndex#create` action to your question.

Comment: Is the model successfully saved or is it only not displaying any messages?

Comment: If I enter the correct information, then everything is properly saved. I am just solving the problem that I don't see any error information if I enter wrong data in the form.

Comment: In else block of create action can you show me output of @rate_index.errors, use puts for that.

Comment: But if the data you enter is invalid, then nothing is saved, right? That means that validations work, but for some reason errors are not being displayed. Do you have any `before_validation` hooks in your model?

Comment: @Manoj - there's nothing. I tried `puts "ERRORS: #{@rate_index.errors}"` and it looks like the `else` branch is accessed by Rails.

Comment: @BroiSatse - if the entered data are invalid, nothing is saved. In model are no `before_validation`s, in the controller is following: `before_action :set_rate_index, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

Comment: Looks fine to me. All I can suggest is to issue `binding.pry` (with `pry`) in controller action and then submit an empty form and inspect what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `valid?` on your object first to trigger the validation

```
@rate_index.valid?
@rate_index.errors
```

Comment: `valid?` should be called  by `save` method, shouldn't it?